# How to get text of child element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

On [this page](http://textanalysisonline.com/spacy-word-lemmatize), I want to enter "looked" or "gone", click the "spaCy Word Lemmatize" button, and then find the "Analysis Result" on the resulting page. I have the code to do everything but I can't isolate the result.

```
Original Text    Analysis Result
-------------    ---------------
looked           look
gone             go
```

This is the HTML result for 'looked':

```
<div class="span5 offset1">
    <h4>Original Text</h4>
    <p>
    looked
    </p>
</div>
<div class="span5">
    <h4>Analysis Result</h4>
    <p>
    look
    </p>
</div>
```

This is my code

```
array = []
myText = ["looked", "gone"]  # I post this array to website.

for a in range(0, len(myText)):

    x = driver.find_element_by_class_name("span5")
    array.append(x.text)

print b -> [u'Original Text\nlooked', u'Original Text\ngone']
```

How can I get only the result, "look" or "go"?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, 'span5')]/p')

Comment: Update your HTML sample as current HTML doesn't contain your output

Comment: I added the post. Can u check?

Comment: Your HTML still doesn't contain the word 'gone'... where is that coming from?

Comment: http://textanalysisonline.com/spacy-word-lemmatize this is the url . 'gone' goes dynamic from my array like 'looked'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you post the following array to website:

```
myText = ["looked", "gone"]
```

As per the resulten [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to extract the texts e.g. **look**, **go** etc, you can use the following solution:

```
my_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.span5:not(.offset1) p")
my_array = [my_element.text for my_element in my_elements]
print(my_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: 
locate all elements containing specific class and child p tag

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, 'span5')]/p')
text = element.text
```

Comment: In Python WebElement doesn't have `getText` attribute. Did you mean `element.text`?

Comment: @Andersson :D, you could edit it and save a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following CSS Selector for that:

```
...
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".span5>p").text
...
```

You can optimize your code:

```
array = []
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".span5>p")

for element in elements:

    array.append(element.text)
```

or more Pythonic:

```
array = [element.text for element in elements]
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks to answer me but output is the same ->  [u'looked', u'gone']

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that div elements are childs of another entity, this is in Java maybe you know how to make it in Python. I created a list of WebElements based on className and a tagName - in your case p tag, after that I'm printing the results.

```
List<WebElement> listofWords= driver.findElement(By.className("other_entity_ClassName_or_something_else")).findElements(By.tagName("p"));
    for (int i = 0; i < listofWords.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(listofWords.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you use two finds instead of a single locator to get what you want with one?